# Entity Framework: How to query a model from other methods before DbContext is disposed?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following Method which accepts a `DataTime` argument when called and returns records according to the date passed.

*Method:*

```
    public static void GetVehicleByReleasedDate(DateTime parameter)
   {
       using (EntityDataModel context = new EntityDataModel())
       {
           var query =
           from vehicle in context.Catalog
           where vehicle.ReleaseDate  >= parameter.Date

           select new
           {
               VehicleMake = vehicle.VehicleMake,
               ManufactureID = vehicle.ManufactureID,
               ManufactureDate = vehicle.ManufacturedDate,
               VehicleIdentificationNumber = vehicle.VehicleIdentificationNumber
           };

           foreach (var vehicle in query)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Format and write result to Console",
               vehicle.ManufactureID,
               vehicle.ManufactureDate,
               vehicle.VehicleIdentificationNumber,
               vehicle.VehicleMake);
           }
       }
   }
```

Instead of the above, I need to return the an `IQueryable` object or the Catalog so that I can perform the query outside of the method.

Like this:

```
    public static IQueryable<Catalog> GetVehicleByReleasedDate()
    {
        using (EntityDataModel context = new EntityDataModel())
        {
            return context.Catalog;
        }
    }
```

Then call the method like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var query = from vehicle in GetVehicleByReleasedDate()
                    where vehicle.ReleaseDate >= DateTime.Now
                    select new
                    {
                        VehicleMake = vehicle.VehicleMake,
                        ManufactureID = vehicle.ManufactureID,
                        ManufactureDate = vehicle.ManufacturedDate,
                        VehicleIdentificationNumber = vehicle.VehicleIdentificationNumber
                    };

        foreach (var vehicle in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:d} {2} {3}",
            vehicle.ManufactureID,
            vehicle.ManufactureDate,
            vehicle.VehicleIdentificationNumber,
            vehicle.VehicleMake);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

As you can tell, I get an error because the using in the `GetVehicleByReleasedDate()` disposes of the context.

*Error message:*

```
The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
```

How do I write this so that I can simply pass queries to the method from another method using the return type before the `Context` is disposed?

**Update:**

Here is the EntityDataModel Class:

```
public partial class EntityDataModel : DbContext
    {
        public EntityDataModel()
            : base("name=EntityDataModel")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Catalog> Catalog { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Model> Model { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Catalog>()
                .Property(e => e.VehicleIdentificationNumber)
                .IsFixedLength();
        }
    }
```

Finally, here is the Catalog model.

```
[Table("Automobile.Catalog")]
public partial class Catalog
{
    [Key]
    public long ManufactureID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string VehicleMake { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(17)]
    public string VehicleIdentificationNumber { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime ManufacturedDate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why? Just move the entire code to the main method...

Comment: Because I want to ultimately put this into a Class Library and I need to be able to just write LINQ to Entity queries without bothering the underline models. In a nutshell, like Encapsulation, I only need exposure to specific elements.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy Can you include your other classes (EntityDataModel and Catalog) in the code above so that we can get a compilable version to work with?

Comment: @TyreeJackson: Please see updates to question:

Comment: @UnaverageGuy HI, please see my answer.  I've provided you with two solutions, one that remains coupled to EF and static.  The other switches to a DI solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IQueryable interface is very lazy. It only evaluates the query when it really needs to. I would suggest using .ToList() on the end of your query to materialize it:

```
var query =
       (from vehicle in context.Catalog
       where vehicle.ReleaseDate  >= parameter.Date
       select new
       {
           VehicleMake = vehicle.VehicleMake,
           ManufactureID = vehicle.ManufactureID,
           ManufactureDate = vehicle.ManufacturedDate,
           VehicleIdentificationNumber = vehicle.VehicleIdentificationNumber
       }).ToList();
```

Otherwise, because of your `using` statement, the context will already have been disposed when IQueryable finally evaluates the query. With `ToList()` you force the query to be materialized and the result will be stored in memory.

**UPDATE:** To make the answer more complete, as Gert Arnold pointed out:

```
// YourStaticClass.cs
public static IEnumerable<Catalog> GetVehicleByReleasedDate(DateTime parameter)
{
    using (var context = new EntityDataModel())
    {
        return context.Catalog
            .Where(x => parameter.Date <= x.ReleaseDate)
            .ToList();
    }
}

// Main.cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var vehicles = YourStaticClass.GetVehicleByReleasedDate(DateTime.Today);

    foreach (var vehicle in vehicles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:d} {2} {3}",
        vehicle.ManufactureID,
        vehicle.ManufactureDate,
        vehicle.VehicleIdentificationNumber,
        vehicle.VehicleMake);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Like this, you materialize the query when the context is still 'undisposed'. You can spit out the data to wherever you need it and process it.

Comment: He's using those types just afterwards. Why is this not good?

Comment: I guess `query` is what will be returned from GetVehicleByReleasedDate. The OP had this problem too, by the way.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks. You think this helps him?

Comment: Well, actually I think only dustmouse's answer gets to the root of the problem.

Comment: As a starting point I like the above answer. It is just readable and you can tell what is going on right away. This post has given me a lot to consider.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**:

If you want to remain coupled to EF and static methods, try a callback setup like this:

```
    public static void GetVehicleByReleasedDate(Func<DbSet<Catalog>, IQueryable<dynamic>> query, Action<IQueryable<dynamic>> useQuery)
    {
        using (EntityDataModel context = new EntityDataModel())
        {
            useQuery(query(context.Catalog));
        }
    }

    public static T GetVehicleByReleasedDate<T>(Func<DbSet<Catalog>, IQueryable<dynamic>> query, Func<IQueryable<dynamic>, T> useQuery)
    {
        using (EntityDataModel context = new EntityDataModel())
        {
            return useQuery(query(context.Catalog));
        }
    }
```

and call it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    GetVehicleByReleasedDate
    (
        catalog=>
        from vehicle in catalog
        where vehicle.ReleaseDate >= DateTime.Now
        select new
        {
            VehicleMake = vehicle.VehicleMake,
            ManufactureID = vehicle.ManufactureID,
            ManufactureDate = vehicle.ManufacturedDate,
            VehicleIdentificationNumber = vehicle.VehicleIdentificationNumber
        },
        query=>
        {
            foreach (var vehicle in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:d} {2} {3}",
                vehicle.ManufactureID,
                vehicle.ManufactureDate,
                vehicle.VehicleIdentificationNumber,
                vehicle.VehicleMake);
            }
        }
    );

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:

If you are interested in decoupling from EF, then try this:

```
public class IEntityRepository : IDisposable
{
    IQueryable<Catalog> GetVehicleByReleasedDate();
}

public class EFEntityRepository : IEntityRepository
{
    private EntityDataModel context = new EntityDataModel():
    public IQueryable<Catalog> GetVehicleByReleasedDate()
    {
        return this.context.Catalog;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.context.Dispose();
        this.context = null;
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    private Func<IEntityRepository> createRepository;
    public Consumer(Func<IEntityRepository> createRepository) { this.createRepository = createRepository; }
    public void OutputData()
    {
        using (var repository = this.createRepository())
        {
            var query = from vehicle in repository.GetVehicleByReleasedDate()
                where vehicle.ReleaseDate >= DateTime.Now
                select new
            {
                VehicleMake = vehicle.VehicleMake,
                ManufactureID = vehicle.ManufactureID,
                ManufactureDate = vehicle.ManufacturedDate,
                VehicleIdentificationNumber = vehicle.VehicleIdentificationNumber
            };

            foreach (var vehicle in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:d} {2} {3}",
                vehicle.ManufactureID,
                vehicle.ManufactureDate,
                vehicle.VehicleIdentificationNumber,
                vehicle.VehicleMake);
            }

        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var consumer = new Consumer(()=>new EFEntityRepository());
        consumer.OutputData();
    }
}
```

Comment: For learning sakes, what if I was not using a `static void` method? For example what if I wanted to return value(s)?

Comment: I am getting this error:

`Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<System.Data.Entity.DbSet<EntityFramework.Catalog>,
System.Linq.IQueryable<EntityFramework.Catalog>>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.`

Comment: @UnaverageGuy I apologize.  I wrote that code without the benefit of Visual Studio or an IDE.  I've fixed it by changing the `GetVehicleByReleasedDate` method to `public static void GetVehicleByReleasedDate(Func<DbSet<Catalog>, IQueryable<dynamic>> query, Action<IQueryable<dynamic>> useQuery)`

Comment: @UnaverageGuy I've added an alternative `GetVehicleByReleasedDate` overload that allows for returning a value T from the usingQuery argument.

Comment: Thanks for the tremendous effort and time to provide the above solution. I am new to EF and so it is a bit to fully understand but I will take this apart piece by piece so that I fully understand what is happening, 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GetVehicleByReleaseDate can take a context as a parameter, so it doesn't control the lifetime of the context, just how the model is manipulated before it is returned.  I would strongly recommend still keeping the lifetime of the context short.

```
public static IQueryable<Catalog> GetVehicleByReleasedDate(EntityDataModel context)
{
    //Do whatever data manipulations you need here.
}
```

However, if GetVehcileByReleaseDate doesn't do much besides return entities from the context, do you even need it?

Have you checked out the repository pattern?  You can create the context for the lifetime of the repository object.  Something along the lines of this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2013/08/23/using-repository-pattern-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: I was with you until the repository pattern. I don't see how that would essentially change the lifespan issue.

Comment: You can wrap the repo in a using block and have access to all of its methods.  It can return a queryable to the consumer, and the consumer can do something with the result set.  And after the consumer is done, it goes out of scope of the using block and the context is disposed.

Comment: Yes, but the essential part is that the caller should control the context's life cycle. Bringing up a repository layer only adds noise to this message. *In itself* it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You can define a repo that takes a context as a constructor.  I personally don't see a problem in using a repo to wrap your context with some well defined operations.  I think it comes down to preference, personally.

Answer (score 0):

You need a dependency injecttion library that controls this for you. Look at Autofac and its life time. I use it for web applications and set the life time of objects created (e.g. DbContext) to the lifetime of the whole HTTP request and it works fine.

http://docs.autofac.org/en/stable/lifetime/index.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25380/Dependency-Injection-with-Autofac#scope